# Build error MC1000 'Object reference doen't set to instance of an

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012, msbuild

I've tried to build my WPF project from VS 2012 but at some point it gave me error with message like this:

> Unknown build error. Object reference does not set to an instance of an object.

However next time I tried to build it everything was fine. So I continued to write code and build and again everything was fine. Then I commited everything to SVN and build happened on TeamCity. Surprisingly it failed and there was a message in a log:

> [MarkupCompilePass1] C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.WinFX.targets(269, 9): error MC1000: Unknown build error, 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

I than ran build on TeamCity manually and it succeeded. Any ideas what is the reason and how to prevent it?

`UPD:` before the first local failed build the only thing I did is just restructuring my project tree i.e. moved some WPF window from one project folder to another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may have some nodes in your config file that are "out of order" - at least that's what most people experience.

```
Ensure the <system.codedom> node between the <system.web> and <system.serviceModel> nodes
```

Comment: What config do you mean?

Answer (score 9):

For me, the problem was an EventSetter that was missing a handler:

```
<EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"></EventSetter>
```

Providing a handler fixed it:

```
<EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="DataGridCell_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"></EventSetter>
```

Comment: You saved me! Same with you!